# Error message when opening Rstudio "evaluation nested too deeply"

Tags: r, rstudio

When I open `Rstudio` I get this error message in my console

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

It happens when I open any script or Rproject. I couldn't find any info on this error and how to address it. I've tried uninstalling R and installing it again but the problem persists. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is my session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] geobr_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.2     magrittr_1.5       class_7.3-15      
 [4] DBI_1.1.0          tools_3.6.2        units_0.6-5       
 [7] Rcpp_1.0.3         KernSmooth_2.23-16 grid_3.6.2        
[10] e1071_1.7-3        classInt_0.4-2     sf_0.8-0
```

Comment: Do you have `~/.Rprofile` and/or `.Renviron` files? If so, please include their contents. Perhaps this is unique to on project or working-directory; is there a `.Rdata` file? If so, perhaps you can move it out of the way (rename it) and restart RStudio. (My guess is that this is not specific to RStudio, but I don't know for certain.)

Comment: There are no  `/.Rprofile`, `.Renviron` nor `Rdata` files. This seems to be a problem with R. I also get the message when I open plain R (not rstudio)

Comment: Do you get the same error when running R without init files? I think `R --vanilla` should be a good test.

Comment: You have quite a few non-base packages attached or loaded. That wouldn't happen in a vanilla R session. Is there a workspace saved that gets loaded? Switch that off. Is there something non-standard in your Rprofile.site file? ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! `R --vanilla` was also returning the error. Roland was right, it was about the Rprofile. There were no files `.Renviron` or `.Rprofile` in the folder of my R project. However, R was reading these files from `C:\Users\user\Documents\Scanned Documents`. I've deleted those files and now it's fine. Thanks again!